# For /f at command line

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I want to save an alias of a certificate in a variable at the command line.
to get the information about my certificate I use:

```
keytool -list -keystore mykeystore -storepass xyz
```

The result is something like:

```
Keystore type: JKS

Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

certreq-ip[...]ac37, 22.06.2015m PrivateKeyEntrym

Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): AE:5A:....**
```

My command looks like:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %A IN ('keytool -list -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass myKeystorePassword') do set alias=%B
```

What I want to get is the string part from "certreq" until the comma.

Can anybody help me? I think space is the wrong delimiter, because I want to get the first item and of course there is no space before. But it is not possible tu use something like `"token=0,1"...`

Comment: Should there be a `FIND` filter in there somewhere, so you only process the `PrivateKeyEntry` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is `certreq-ip[...]ac37`, then:

```
for /f "delims=," %a in ('keytool -list -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass myKeystorePassword^|findstr PrivateKeyEntry') do set alias=%a
```

seems to work.  You're filtering on `PrivateKeyEntry` as Stavr00 suggests and using a comma as the delimiter.  Remember, if you put it in a batch file, `%a` will need to become `%%a`.

Comment: Yess, this is working. I already tried the findstr option, but I didn't know to set the ^ to connect is (I think that's not needed in a bat file).
%a and %%a is clear. 
Nice job!

Comment: It's the "`|`" (called a "pipe") that connects the two commands; the "`^`" is needed (both on the command-line and in a batch file) to "protect" the pipe symbol (otherwise, the command-processor will try and interpret it too soon, during processing of the `for` command as a whole).  With the `^`, the pipe is not interpreted until processing of the command invoked _by_ the `for` command.